# Can we do simple binary dumps of netCDF files?

Tags: binary-data, netcdf

I am trying to examine a netCDF output file through ncdump, and also through the linux "od" utility.  I have a question about what I am seeing.  For instance, from ncdump, I get one line (out of many lines) of data

```
-10.55448, -10.52312, -10.4916, -10.46023, -10.42887, -10.39742, -10.36587,
```

Now, I try to examine the same file with the "od" utility at the same spot where I expect to find the above numbers,

```
od -c -Ad -tf4 -j 2017 output.nc
```

and I get something totally different:

```
0002017 311   c 344 301   ( 337   ' 301   (   ^ 260 301   ' 335 224 301
             -28.548723     -10.4919815      -22.045975      -18.607985
0002033   '   ] 034 301   & 334 245 301   &   [ 320 301   % 332 235 301
              -9.772742      -20.732494      -26.044506      -19.731516
```

That is, the recognizable float numbers are not at all what I get from ncdump.

Not only do the numbers I expect not show up in the spot where I expected them, but the first couple of numbers in the od output, -28.54872 and -10.49198 (rounded to 5 places), do not show up anywhere at all in the ncdump output.

Is this reasonable?  Does netCDF mix a great deal of metadata in with its data so that it is impossible to do a straight binary dump of a netCDF file?  Or is something odd going on?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate thought that comes to mind is, how did you know how long the header was?  You are skipping the first 2017 bytes, but how did you work that out?  I suspect you are dumping digits that actually form part of the metadata, not the data itself, hence the reason you don't see the numbers with ncdump | grep X

ncview is *very* robust, it reads the header and knows exactly where the data records are - I would trust the output.  I would always advise interrogating an reading netcdf files with utilities/packages that are specifically designed for the file format.

Sorry I can't be more specific/helpful but it is difficult to investigate or answer this without access to the files.

Comment: I experimented with the offset in "od", looking for the value that would produce reasonable looking output.  2017 was by far the only candidate in the neighborhood.  And I do trust the ncdump output.  At least, I trust what it is showing me.  I just wonder 1) what it might not be showing and 2) why can I not find the same data in od output?

Comment: ncdump shows you the header interpreted as text, i.e. it tells you the missing values, units etc if those metadata are defined, if you trawling randomly through the header with od you are showing the raw bytes of the metadata.  So for 1) ncdump is showing you everything, in a form that is understandable and 2) I doubt you have dumped the whole file with od by the sounds of it, and you might even end up splitting 2 or 4 byte integers or 4/8 byte doubles by mistake (you said "reasonable" looking output, when it is not reasonable that is usually when you are splitting 4 or 8 byte words